# SQL Server - update multiply tables with sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I try to update several tables according to another sub query I have.
what is the syntax?

I tried:

```
;with sub_query as (....)
update T 
set X = Y 
from table1 T 
inner join sub_query on ...

update T 
set X = Y 
from table2 T 
inner join sub_query on ...
```

but I got an error in the update `table2` query:

> Invalid object name 'sub_query'.

What should be the syntax to update the second query? I don't want to write the `sub_query` again because it is a very complicated query.

Thanks!

Comment: The **CTE** is **only** available for **one statement** - it cannot be used twice. If you need it twice, you'll have to think of another way: create a view, store the values into a temp table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW view_sub_query .....

UPDATE T SET X=Y FROM table1 T INNER JOIN view_sub_query ON ...
UPDATE T SET X=Y FROM table2 T INNER JOIN view_sub_query ON ...
```

If you have to use it in many places use a table function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fun_sub_query .....

UPDATE T SET X=Y FROM table1 T INNER JOIN fun_sub_query ON ...
UPDATE T SET X=Y FROM table2 T INNER JOIN fun_sub_query ON ...
```

Comment: why did you change your answer? I created a view and it works well. The view include only the sub query, and I run the update statements separated.   Thanks you!

Comment: Well, I thought it could work but when I tried on my system it seemed not to be working and I had no time for a deeper understanding; now I make some more tests and effectively it is possible to update using views, I'll amend my answer. Thanks

Comment: @ThanosMarkou Why are you saying that? CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
 [Date] [datetime] NULL,
 [product] [nvarchar](32) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_1]
AS
SELECT     [Date], [product]
FROM         dbo.Table_1
GO
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES('2015-01-01', 'Apples')
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES('2015-01-01', 'Oranges')
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES('2015-01-02', 'Apples')
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES('2015-01-02', 'Oranges')
INSERT INTO Table_1 VALUES('2015-01-03', 'Apples')
GO
UPDATE T SET Date = v.Date FROM Table_1 T INNER JOIN View_1 V ON T.Date = v.Date
GO

Answer (score 0):

`CTE table` is only used once after create it! You can use table variable or temp table instead of it. Like this:

```
CREATE @sub_query (...)
INSERT INTO sub_query ....

UPDATE ...
```